# Firebase frame work shows errors in Xcode 3.2 :(

Tags: xcode, firebase

i am using older version of xcode 3.2 i downloaded firebase frame work for ios from the official site and successfully imported into my project but it shows a lots of errors :(

so my question is, is there any older version of firebase for xcode 3.2 i googled everywhere but cant find any so please give me the link if firebase supports xcode 3.2

Thanx in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

Why you're using Xcode v.3.2. It's no longer supporting to the latest version of your Mac OSX and your iOS device. Please get a new Mac (if required) and then download latest Xcode.

Don't try to solve those errors. Please update your system.